# javascript prepending to head?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use jquery UI for slider in a bookmarklet. and jquery ui requires to include the file after normal jquery file.

So what I've tried so far was just appending the script to header while making sure that ui get added after normal jquery but this did not work i suspect it might be because i appended it and not pre pended it.

So i am now looking for ways to pre pend in Javascript after some time searching i've found :

```
var parent_head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jqueryUI, parent_head.firstChild);
```

This however seems to append it in a normal way.

Is there a better way?

Comment: How about replacing `appendChild` with `insertBefore`?

Comment: The position a script is inserted dynamically does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) with the first child as the insertion point.

```
parent_head.insertBefore(jqueryUI, parent_head.firstChild)
```

For example,

```
var list = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(list);
list.innerHTML = "<li>First</li><li>Second</li>";

var newItem = document.createElement('li');
newItem.innerHTML = "Firster";

list.insertBefore(newItem, list.firstChild);
```

shows

- Firster
- First
- Second

Comment: yea that worked seems it wasn't the problem bah i guess I'll have to make my own sliders. thanks very much for help